# Running Azure CLI script in Azure DevOps Pipeline however unable to find the CLI script

Tags: azure-devops, command-line-interface

```
param (

    $ProjectFilePath= $(Buildin.SourcesDirectory)\TESTREPO7\RuleConfig.json
    
    $ExecutableFilePath= $(Buildin.SourcesDirectory)\TESTREPO7\Studio.zip\Studio\UiPath.Studio.CommandLine.exe
    
    $OutputFilePath= $(Buildin.SourcesDirectory)\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss')-Workflow-Analysis.json
    
    )

Write-Output "$(Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm:ss') - STARTED - Workflow Analyzer CLI Script"

$Command = "$ExecutableFilePath analyze -p $ProjectFilePath"
Invoke-Expression $Command | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFilePath

Write-Output "$(Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm:ss') - COMPLETED - Workflow Analyzer CLI Script"
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

**Error:**

```
##[section]Starting: Azure CLI UiPathWorkFlow 
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure CLI
Description  : Run Azure CLI commands against an Azure subscription in a Shell script when running on Linux agent or Batch script when running on Windows agent.
Version      : 1.152.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli
==============================================================================
##[error]Script failed with error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'C:\agent1\_work\362\s\TESTREPO7\UiPathAnalyze.ps1'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.
##[section]Finishing: Azure CLI UiPathWorkFlow
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Very important-  When on a local computer, uiath.studio.commandline.exe (workflow analyzer) has rules stored in User directory (%LocalAppData%\UiPath\Rules =  C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\UiPath\Rules).   How would I be able to input this information in the script provided above??

Azure CLI latest version installed on azure DevOps agent server.

Tried adding environment parameter but not sure what to enter but this error occurred anyways. Added Environment made did not fix the error.

added both below environmentals—

PATH $(Buildin.SourcesDirectory)\TESTREPO7\UipathAnalyze.ps1

Build.SourcesDirectory $(Buildin.SourcesDirectory)\TESTREPO7\UipathAnalyze.ps1

Answer (score 0):

Check this doc [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services), the path should be `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` instead of `$(Buildin.SourcesDirectory)`

The error message is: `Unable to locate executable file: 'C:\agent1\_work\362\s\TESTREPO7\UiPathAnalyze.ps1'`

The UipathAnalyze.ps1 is the code you shared and it it the Script Path in the task Azure CLI, right? We need open the folder path `C:\agent1\_work\362\s\TESTREPO7` to check if the file exists.

In addition, could you successfully run the .ps1 file on the local agent machine?

Comment: Could you run it via Hosted agent and then kindly share the reuslt here? By the way, you have added environment, where did you add the variables, local machine or pipeline variable?

Comment: I added environmental variables but these did fix the error.  Currently have PATH and the value is $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TESTREPO7\Studio\Studio\uipath.studio.commandline.exe

Comment: Found the following when searching for agent1:   C:\agent\Workfolder_CloudUiPathAgent03\_tasks\AzureCLI_46e4be58-730b-4389-8a2f-ea10b3e5e815   which has the correct date of my troubleshooting.

Comment: When searching for TESTREPO7 which is a folder in DevOps repository, I found three (4,5,6 ) folders like this C:\agent\Workfolder_CloudUiPathAgent03\4\s\TESTREPO7.  When I looked at inside there is uipathanalyze.ps1 which are identical in all three folders.  Note- I am running azure CLI and  because the paths on the script are local computer paths.

Comment: PATH is $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TESTREPO7\Studio\Studio\uipath.studio.commandline.exe

Comment: A search for uipath.studio.commandline.exe does not exist on this server.

Comment: This is the error that occurred when I ran the pipeline again tonight with $(Build.SourcesDirectory) included.   Azure CLI 2.x is not installed on this machine.
Script failed with error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'c:\agent\_work\4\s\TESTREPO7\UiPathAnalyze.ps1'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.

Comment: C:\Users\user01>az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.20.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.20.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6",
  "extensions": {}
}

So I do not know why the azure CLI error is occurring?  had to run the cmd as Admin.

Comment: Hi @d1260, you could edit your issue description and add the update, in addition, it seems that your are using power shell script, and you are using Azure CLI task instead of Power shell task or Azure Power shell Task.

Comment: So I have a Azure CLI script that I added to a text file and saved as a ps1.  What should I be saving this script in the text file as?,... what ending should it be?  I believe the term is what file ending (ie. XXXX.***) should be used for a Azure CLI script if it was to be wrapped into a file?

Comment: If the script can be wrapped can you please tell me what changes are required in the script as well?